# @protected in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, inheritance, protected

I have a simple class:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@interface MyTableViewController : UITableViewController
{
@protected
    NSFetchedResultsController *_fetchedResultsController;
}
```

And one more:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyChildTableViewController : MyTableViewController
{
}

- (void)someMethod;
```

The problem is that I can't use `_fetchedResultsController` in `MyChildTableViewController` class. I get compile-time error: '_fetchedResultsController' undeclared (first use in this function)`

What's wrong here?

Comment: P.S.: `self->_fetchedResultsController` works...

Comment: As you figured out, adding `self->` worked. I've also heard that switching to LLVM will make it work without that, and the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocDefiningClasses.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH12-87895) seems to indicate it should.

Comment: ughoavgfhw, please, write your comment as answer - your advice helped me (I've changed `C/C++ Compiler Version` to `LLVM compiler 2.0`) and I want to mark it as correct and close question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ughoavgfhw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/458390/ughoavgfhw) posted right answer in comments. I've asked him (in comments, also) to rewrite it as an answer - so I can accept it. But he didn't. So I will post my own answer, simply to close the question and remove it from unanswered.

The solution:
Change `C/C++ Compiler Version` to `LLVM compiler 2.0` in your project's settings.

Answer (score -1):

I also had the same problem, by using self->, everything worked fine.