# how to prevent access to private variable at run time in objective C?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I know that I can use @private keyword to declare my instance variable private. Which I believe it will only get enforced at compile time.

Do you know of any way to prevent other users from accessing my private variable at run time?

I'm asking this because I'm building a static library which will get distributed to other developers and I don't want them to have access to my private variables.

Comment: What are you trying to prevent, specifically? Are these other developers considered hostile in some way?

Answer (score 2):

You can't prevent a determined person from messing with data at runtime (once they know the address of an object in memory and it's in an allocated space that is freely writable by the current process, there is always a way to change it).  The best you could probably do is to obfuscate it, e.g. show only a `void*`, allocate memory somewhere else and cast.

Comment: Is this also true in other compiled languages like C++ and Java?

Comment: It's at least true in C++.  For instance, consider: `class X { private: int i; };`.  If I have `X x;`, the *compiler* might not let me access `i` but that is trivial to override; for instance I could declare my own `struct Y { int i; };` of the same size, and use `((Y*)&x)->i = 3` to set it *anyway*.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using @private in your (public) .h file you can declare the instance variables in a class extension in your .m file. This will also not prevent a determined person from accessing it, as @KevinGrant correctly said, but at least other people will not see the declaration (and the debugger will not show it, I assume).

Added: See e.g. [Objective C - Make iVars hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11707495/objective-c-make-ivars-hidden) for a discussion on that topic.

Comment: yup. I'm already hiding any mention of the private variable in the public header file. Now I want to secure it at run time.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can prevent other access to private variable at run time.Because others can use KVC and KVO to get and change your private variable. Maybe you can make lots of relationship between your private variable , if other change it , they will get wrong answer , maybe it can prevent other to change your private variable